# Cipher not initialized for encryption/decryption

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, unwrap

When I run this code:

```
  public static byte[] unwrap(PrivateKey privateKey, byte[] wrappedKey) throws Exception {
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");  
      cipher.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, privateKey);

      return cipher.doFinal(wrappedKey);
  }
```

The return statement line throws this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cipher not initialized for encryption/decryption
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCipherState(Cipher.java:1754)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2157)
    at x.y.z.decrypt.Main.unwrap(Main.java:47)
    at x.y.z.decrypt.Main.main(Main.java:33)
```

If I use DECRYPT_MODE it seems to try and decrypt, but I'm after unwrap. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your Java version?

Comment: I've tried 8 and 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You initialized the cipher with UNWRAP_MODE mode, but you are trying to encrypt. You have to use `wrap` and `unwrap` functions, see the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#wrap(java.security.Key))

```
unwrap​(byte[] wrappedKey, String wrappedKeyAlgorithm, int wrappedKeyType)
```